# Remove digital artifacts (clicking sound) from read errors on a CD-r

Tags: editing, clicks

There is good software and a lot of information on how to repair clicks and pops on audio sourced from vinyl.

When audio is burned to a CD-r playing the disc can produce a clicking sound. The error correction (C2) will try to keep the sync but in some cases filling the gaps can result in audible clicks, often at regular intervals. In louder vocal parts the volume of these clicks can vary.

What is the best approach to repair this?

An example can be heard on the official release of this track.
[Prince - Stand Up And B Strong (Official Audio)](https://youtu.be/wwhjYRXoO_U) on YouTube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a myriad de-clickers available, from freeware [Audacity](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/click_removal.html) -  up through [Steinberg's WaveLab](https://steinberg.help/wavelab_elements_plug_in_reference/v9.5/en/_shared/topics/plug_ref/restore_rig/restore_rig_declicker_r.html) - right up to [Izotope RX](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/rx.html).

This site doesn't do specific recommendations, but you get what you pay for, of course.

Here are all the clicks - the inverse process of course removes them rather than isolates them..

[image]

I am rather surprised, as that link does appear to be an official release, that no-one spent the 30 seconds necessary to do it before releasing it.

Comment: Totally surprising. Steaming services, CD, 24bit-96kHz FLAC, all sourced from the same CD-r. I bet the £119.95 vinyl 180 grams has the same clicks on it. It's at least on 3 tracks.